# Disable auto wrap long line in Python code in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I use Visual Studio Code to write Python code with Pylint.

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> (save), the editor wraps a long line into multiple short lines. How do I disable the action or configure wrap column count to 120 (default is 80)?

I have tried  `"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--max-line-length=120"]` and `"editor.wordWrapColumn": 120`, but it didn't work.

Comment: Do you have automatic formatting turned on? VS Code itself won't reformat anything, so `editor.wordWrapColumn` won't affect that as that -- along with `editor.wordWrap` -- only affect how to display long lines, not rewrite them.

Comment: If you use `autopep8`, do the following: open "Settings"-> search "python formatting autopep8 args" -> click "Add Item" -> type `--max-line-length=120` (change 120 to you preferred length).

Comment: Pylint is a linter, not a formatter, so it won't change your code, just point out problems.

Answer (score 284, accepted):

Check your Python formatting provider.

```
"python.formatting.provider": "autopep8"
```

I guess in your case it is not Pylint which keeps wrapping the long lines, but `autopep8`. Try setting `--max-line-length` for `autopep8` instead.

```
"python.formatting.autopep8Args": [
    "--max-line-length=200"
]
```

Comment: It also helps if the linter behaves similarly to the formatter: "python.linting.pep8Args": ["--max-line-length=120"]

Comment: For information about other available arguments, see https://pypi.org/project/autopep8/

Comment: TLDR: PEP8 indicates that the ideal line wrapping limit for Python is 80, so this is the default for the autopep8.

Comment: with pure point & click achieve this with: "Code -> Preferences -> Settings". Then select "Extensions -> Python". Browse through to "Formatting: Autopep8 Args" and its "Add item", in the proposed box, add "--max-line-length=200"

Comment: `"--ignore=E501"` to completely ignore max-line-length.

Comment: To get this to work you may also have to change the **Editor: Word Wrap Column** setting.

Comment: @Jeppe How can we that kind of setting exists? It works perfectly thank!

Answer (score 15):

When using custom arguments, each top-level element of an argument string that's separated by space on the command line must be a separate item in the arguments list. For example:

```json
"python.formatting.autopep8Args": [ 
  "--max-line-length", "120", "--experimental" 
],
"python.formatting.yapfArgs": [
  "--style", "{based_on_style: chromium, indent_width: 20}"
],
"python.formatting.blackArgs": [
  "--line-length", "100"
]
```

For proper formatting of these Python settings you can check
*[Formatter-specific settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_formatterspecific-settings)*:

Also check the answers here:

*[Allow statements before imports with Visual Studio Code and autopep8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54030320/vscode-autopep8-allow-statements-before-imports/54031007#54031007)*

Answer (score 9):

In VS Code version **1.82.2** (2023), the location for parsing autopep8's arguments has changed.

Now you should add the following to the **top level** of the `settings.json` file:

```json
"autopep8.args": ["--max-line-length=120"]
```

or remove the lenght limit completely:

```json
"autopep8.args": ["--ignore=E501"]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `yapf` as your formatter then the option is `column_limit`. For example, from `settings.json`:

```json
"python.formatting.provider": "yapf",
"python.formatting.yapfArgs": [
    "--style={based_on_style: google, indent_width: 4, column_limit: 150}"
],
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried the solution with different way. Search in VSC settings for "Autopep8". And as you can see there is an "Add Item" button in here. You can simply click it and paste the code there. The code will add in your "settings.json" file.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score -1):

Autopep8 requires `--aggressive` in order to recommend non-whitespace changes:

```
"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--max-line-length", "120", "--aggressive"]
```

This will wrap the long lines for you.

Comment: I believe OP is asking how to disable wrapping, not how to enable it