# Allow statements before imports with Visual Studio Code and autopep8

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, autopep8

I'm using Visual Studio Code with the Python plugin and autopep8 with:

```
"editor.formatOnSave": true
```

I have local packages I need to import, so I have something like:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/packages')
import localpackage
```

but when I save, Visual Studio Code/autopep8 moves all import statements before the code, so Python can't find my local package.

```
import sys
import localpackage
sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/packages')
```

How can I tell Visual Studio Code/autopep8 that it's okay to put a statement before imports, or is there a more correct way of importing local packages?

As a workaround, it looks like it's fine if you import in an *if* statement:

```
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/packages')
if 'localpackage' not in sys.modules:
    import localpackage
```

Comment: I don't know what the flag is to autopep8, but once you find it you can specify it with `"python.formatting.autopep8Args"`.

Comment: The entry in settings.json should be `"python.formatting.autopep8Args": ["--ignore", "E402"]` (see complete answer below).

Answer (score 55, accepted):

1. Open settings
2. Search for autopep8. You should see the following results:

   [image]
3. Click on "Edit in settings.json" under the first option
4. Add the following argument to the User Settings JSON file:

   ```
   "python.formatting.autopep8Args": ["--ignore", "E402"]
   ```

   [image]

This tells `autopep8` to ignore error 402 which is: "module level import not at top of file" (here's the [list of errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZ4Ib.png) in pep8)

You can use this same method to change any of the `autopep8` settings. For example, if you only wanted to fix indentation, you can use `"python.formatting.autopep8Args": ["--select", "E1"]`

The [autopep8 readme](https://github.com/hhatto/autopep8/blob/master/README.rst) has more information on the available options.

Comment: As a side note, I've only gotten one argument at a time to work. If I try to do something like: `"python.formatting.autopep8Args": ["--ignore", "E402", "--ignore", "E401"]` only one of the two arguments work (usually the second one). I'm not sure why this is, and if someone has a solution, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @wilk you need to separate them with commas like `"--ignore", "E401,E701"`

Comment: Is there something I can put in the setup.cfg?

Comment: now in vscode, you need to search for autopep8, click "add item", add --ignore=E402 and click "OK".

Answer (score 44):

If you don't want to generally disable import sorting, but just disable it for specific lines, you can use the following pragmas at the end of each line:

```
# noqa
```

or

```
# nopep8
```

Like so for your example:

```
import sys # noqa
sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/packages') # noqa
import localpackage
```

Comment: Love this approach!

Comment: You can also use a more specific line like this `# noqa: E402`

Answer (score 3):

Due to changes in vscode (~1.84) the syntax in willk's answer `"python.formatting.autopep8Args": ["--ignore", "E402"]` no longer works, the new format is:

`"autopep8.args": ["--ignore", "E402"]`

[docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/formatting)

Comment: Lifesaver, I was curious of why that argument grayed out when I am coding recently and constantly adding the # noqa: E402 comments. This worked for me.