# Statement before import not working, database keeps getting erased everytime I run tests

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, flask, autopep8

I'm following the flask mega tutorial by M Grinberg, which at a point runs some tests for new functionalities. Every time I run tests.py the database is erased (luckly it's easy te re create)
This is the supposed problematic part of the code in the test.py file:

```
import os 
os.environ['DATABASE_URL'] = 'sqlite://' 

from datetime import datetime, timezone, timedelta
import unittest
from app import app, db
from app.models import User, Post
```

the `os.environ['DATABASE_URL'] = 'sqlite://'` statement is meant to override the database and change the application configuration to direct SQLAlchemy to use an in-memory SQLite database during the tests, so the test doesn't mess up the actual database.

It seems someone else already found the same problem and their solution was to change from autopep8 to Black Formatter, it also pointed me to [Allow statements before imports with Visual Studio Code and autopep8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54030320/allow-statements-before-imports-with-visual-studio-code-and-autopep8/54031007#54031007) where the solution was to mark the statement before the imports with #noqa, or to add the comment "autopep8.args": ["--ignore", "E402"] to the autopep args in the settings. None of this has worked for me so far, so I figure I ask the question again.

EDIT: I applied format with both autopep8 and black formatter, no changes though, I'm starting to think maybe the problems is somewhere else? Thanks for the help!
[with autopep8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsCDR.png)

[with black-formatter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsGJU.png)

Comment: Is your live code getting the database from the environment variable, or is it hard-coded?

Comment: its' all done from the environment variable, if there is anything I should be looking at?

Comment: i'm sorry, what do you mean by live code?

Comment: I mean the "not test code".

Comment: ohh, well the database is created within the environment workplace, using flask db migrate and upgrade. the os.environ['DATABASE_URL'] = 'sqlite://' statement is suppossed to implement a mockup databse so the tests dont run on the actual database, but this is not working properly and the actual database gets erased after running the tests.

Comment: Your path in the test unit should be something like: conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:').

Comment: This setting(`"autopep8.args": ["--ignore", "E402"]`) works for me, do you have both `"editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.autopep8",` and `"autopep8.args": ["--ignore", "E402"]`. also it would be best to show your full *settings.json* as well as your list of extensions and more useful details.

Comment: "This setting("autopep8.args": ["--ignore", "E402"]) works for me, do you have both "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.autopep8", and "autopep8.args": ["--ignore", "E402"]" yes I did. then i changed to black formatter, it didn't do the trick either.

Comment: the extension are ipynb support autopep8, black formatter, C/C++, copilot, css Language Feature, Git, GIthub, HTML, JavaScript Debugger, JSON, JSON-zain, Jupyter, Pylance, POwerShell, Python...and some more

Comment: "[python]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.autopep8"
    },
    "python.formatting.provider": "none",
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "workbench.editorAssociations": {
        "*.sqlite": "default"
    },
    "autopep8.args": [
        "\"autopep8.args\": [\"--ignore\", \"E402\"]"
    ],
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.autopep8",
    "editor.defaultFoldingRangeProvider": "ms-python.autopep8",

Comment: Exactly the same settings.json, [no problems with me](https://imgur.com/ZKewtzg.png). Can you show your settings.json page? Again, [I set it to `Black` without any issues too](https://imgur.com/iyk5ZQ5.png). Please edit your question post to add all the details.

Comment: just getting back to this, sorry it's been a hectic week, I'll edit the post with the details in a moment (though it won't be a nice video like yours,  just screenshots :( )

Comment: I'm very sorry, but you can [report your issue at GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/new/choose) and provide the appropriate logs and other information as needed.