# Python extension in Visual Studio Code breaks lines and moves code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Using Python extension in Visual Studio Code and when enabled, it wants to put hard returns in my long lines and move library imports to the top. How do I turn these "features" off?

I've tried to disable linting, but the only thing that works is to disable the entire extension.

Comment: Possible solutions in [this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47406741/visual-studio-code-disable-auto-wrap-long-line)

Comment: Please could you provide a screen sample of the error you are getting? What do you mean by `How do I turn these "features" off`. I.e. are you getting any messages that's prompting you to do this? If so, please provide the message and then we can helop.

Comment: There is no error. When I edit a line and move my cursor away or hit enter, something inserts a hard return if it considers the line to be too long. If i catch it quick enough I can ctrl+z to undo it and it will stay as one line until I edit again. Highly irritating. I was being sarcastic in calling it a feature, but it feels like a bug.