# vscode reformat to wider length

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am using `autopep8` as formatter for python in vscode.

Earlier when I used to save the file, vscode used to autoformat the file and wrap long lines. For example:

```py
results['flagReason'] = results.apply(
    lambda x: flagger(x, return_type='reason'), axis=1)
results['flagMessage'] = results.apply(
    lambda x: flagger(x, return_type='message'), axis=1)
```

But what I write (or want) is:

```py
results['flagReason'] = results.apply(lambda x: flagger(x, return_type='reason'), axis=1)
results['flagMessage'] = results.apply(lambda x: flagger(x, return_type='message'), axis=1)
```

For this, from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47406741/disable-auto-wrap-long-line-in-visual-studio-code), I changed the settings of vscode and added the following in settings file:

```json
"python.formatting.autopep8Args": ["--max-line-length", "120", "--experimental"]
```

The issue is when I try to reformat after adding these settings, the file does not reformat and wrapped lines do not unwrap i.e. does not change to how i want.

Please help...

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following settings and see if it solves your question:

```
"editor.wordWrap": "wordWrapColumn",
"editor.wordWrapColumn": 120
```