# Break line in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

VS Code keeps wrapping lines automatically at the line seen in the image. How can I disable this behaviour? I have already tried windows+z and alt+z

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable auto wrap long line in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47406741/disable-auto-wrap-long-line-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: Does it actually insert a newline or does it just wrap the display of the line? You know what I mean? Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: @vatbub That's specific to Python, and OP here isn't using Python. IDK what language that is.

Comment: I know, but VS Code has the same option for most languages and since I also was unable to infer the language used, I used this Python question as an example.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can search Ruler in setting where you see an hypertext "Edit in settings.json" click it and you will see an array named "editor.rulers" make sure it is empty like this :

```
"editor.rulers": [
    
]
```

Comment: You don't need to disable all rulers. I have rulers enabled and don't have this behaviour. Something else is responsible for it.

Comment: Okay I thought this might be a possible answer.

Comment: I think my answer is right..